# Adding radio buttons logic in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a boolean field for gender in my data model. This is the script that I'm using to render the radio button on the view

```
<label class= 'sniglet'> Gender</label>
<%= f.radio_button(:gender, 'Male', :class => 'form-control radio-inline') %> Male
<%= f.radio_button(:gender, 'Female', :class => 'form-control radio-inline') %>Female
```

How do I write the logic that when the gender field is true the user is a female and false it's  male.

Answer (score 2):

Re-write your tags so they look like this:

```
<%= f.radio_button :gender, true, :class => 'form-control radio-inline' %> Male
<%= f.radio_button :gender, false, :class => 'form-control radio-inline' %>Female
```

Comment: ...and what error would that be? Try putting the true/false outside of the brackets. `...radio-inline'), true %> `

Comment: Text outside the brackets need to display the textI want to display on the page. Its a syntax error.

Comment: I just editted my post - try that new solution. It should work.

Answer (score 0):

we can use `simple_form`

```
<%= f.input :gender, :collection => ["Male","Female"], :as => :radio_buttons, :checked =>"Male",:item_wrapper_class => 'inline' ,:label => "Gender" %>
```

Comment: Is this method object aware?

Comment: Sorry I am not getting you please ask me in brief

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Rails form helper documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button), you'll need to do something like this:

```
<%= f.radio_button :gender, true %>Female
<%= f.radio_button :gender, false %>Male
```

If you have a `:gender` attribute populated with either `true` or `false`, this should populate the radio buttons correctly for you. If it still doesn't work, you'll be best showing your form & controller code :)